# Why do i get a 404 on some users from the same application on ASP.NET Core on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, http-status-code-404, windows-authentication, .net-4.6

I am very new to ASP.NET, IIS and Webapplications, so maybe my question is quite stupid, but i have searched for 3 days now and i just don't get it :-(

I have build a application in ASP.NET Core 1.1 using EF6 on the full framework 4.5.2. I build it from scratch using windows authentification. Once i had a little bit to show i published the site on a server with IIS 8.5 running. The site works, everyone in our company is authenticated and it still is.

Meanwhile i was working on the site and added some new features, including the Novell.directory.Ldap.NETStandard package. Because of this package i changed the target framework to 4.6.

Now the fun part...
I published the upgraded site on IIS using the exact same configuration. The site works as expected. But for 50% of my users it ends in a 404 error and a blank screen.
If the same users starts the "old" site they can use it as expected.

Has anyone an idea, what the problem could be, or at least how i can find out what is going wrong exactly?

Btw i am not able to do debugging on the Server, since it is protected with a smartcard.

Maybe there is a trick so i get the debug error page like on IIS Express?

Thanks in advance for all your thoughts :-)

**Edit:**
Ok, i found something out. The problem comes from the Windows Authentification. On some machines (users?) the `User.Identity.Name returns null`

**Edit 2:**
This is my web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" processPath=".\DocudatWebApp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=11" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And here my Program.cs

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 3**
Ok, i gave up on windows authentication and switched to OIDC.
Now everything is working fine.

Comment: With no code it's impossible to say. I suggest you add some error logging that you can view from the backend (e.g. Elmah) to trace your problems.

Comment: Hi DavidG! I am sorry, have not been here for a long weekend. I will have look into this an try to give a better view on this.